# How can someone add a sql server table from a different database to a ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have a database `labor` which contains the tables that the rails application has created and i have a different database called `data_collection` that contains a table called `employees` that i need to pull information so that my application can use it. It doesn't need to be edited from the application only readable. All of these databases are sql server. How would i go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could define an activerecord connection for each Model you have , here some example .
[link](http://weare.buildingsky.net/2006/12/06/multiple-concurrent-database-connections-with-activerecord)

have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You could also see if your friendly DBA has set up a Linked server connection for you to use.  Or you could try using the [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) feature in TSQL.  Or you could just do what @andrea suggests.